# Ionic using Oauth retrieve and manipulate data, help needed

Tags: http, post, ionic-framework, oauth-2.0, multipartform-data

code in dog provider ->

```
public getAuth(): string {
let final_token: string;
var form = new FormData();
form.append("username", "email@gmail.com");-
form.append("password", "randomPass");
form.append("client_id", "1");
form.append("client_secret", "my_secret");
form.append("grant_type", "password");

var settings = {
  async: true,
  crossDomain: true,
  url: "oauth/token",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "postman_token"
  },
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
  data: form
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
  let obj = JSON.parse(response);
  final_token = obj.token_type + " " + obj.access_token;
  return final_token;
});
return final_token;
```

This is the method i use to extract the data that i need from the api which is using Oauth2. It currently works , i receive the token. But when i go to process it in ionic in my class through the 'dog' provider:

```
provider: DogProvider;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    dogProvider: DogProvider
  ) {
    this.provider = dogProvider;
  }

ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log("this.provider.getAuth()");
  }
```

It returns undefined, how do I fix this? Am I supposed to subscribe or map the result, I have no clue honestly because when I log in the method that I call it pulls out the right auth string but only after it has returned undefined ( I think this is something to do with the jquery because it is waiting for the document to finish loading but I may be wrong and I do not know how to fix it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right, js doesn't wait for the method to finish and it gets executed later.
I used await and async to fix the problem.

Comment: you should use promises